# Unable to centre bootstrap media card on small mobile device screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code using flexbox/centre bootstrap  media card works correctly, apart from when viewed on a mobile sized screen, where the boxes are aligned to the left. I'd like them centred in the screen.

I looked at changing align-self-left to centre or text-align: center but it does not appear to work. I tried applying this to the article and row below. Not sure why it will not centre correctly?

CSS

```css
.card .card-body {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.boxFixDw {
  display:inline-block; width: 285px;
  color: #1576b9;
}
```

```html
HTML

<div class="row flexbox-wrap">
  
      <div class="col-lg-4 flexbox-equalise">
        <article class="media card card-1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="card-body align-self-left">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-headline boxFixDw">LATEST RESOURCES</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">More added each week.</p>
                   <a href="X" class="button product_type_subscription add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">VIEW NOW</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
      </div>
  
        <div class="col-lg-4 flexbox-equalise">
        <article class="media card card-1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="card-body card-body-left">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-headline boxFixDw">JOIN NOW</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">For instant access.</p>
                   <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalJoin" class="button product_type_subscription add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">SIGN UP</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
      </div>
  
           <div class="col-lg-4 flexbox-equalise">
        <article class="media card card-1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="card-body card-body-left">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-headline boxFixDw">SAMPLE RESOURCES</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">Check the quality.</p>
                  <a href="X/" class="button product_type_subscription add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">VIEW NOW</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
      </div>
  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> apart from when viewed on a mobile sized screen, where the boxes are
>   aligned to the left.

To center the cards on mobile you need to change `align-items: flex-start;` to `align-items: center;` for the `.media` through media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .media {
        align-items: center !important;
    }
}
```

```css
.card .card-body {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.boxFixDw {
  display:inline-block; width: 285px;
  color: #1576b9;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .media {
  align-items: center !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row flexbox-wrap">
  
      <div class="col-lg-4 flexbox-equalise">
        <article class="media card card-1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="card-body align-self-left">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-headline boxFixDw">LATEST RESOURCES</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">More added each week.</p>
                   <a href="X" class="button product_type_subscription add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">VIEW NOW</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
      </div>
  
        <div class="col-lg-4 flexbox-equalise">
        <article class="media card card-1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="card-body card-body-left">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-headline boxFixDw">JOIN NOW</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">For instant access.</p>
                   <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalJoin" class="button product_type_subscription add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">SIGN UP</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
      </div>
  
           <div class="col-lg-4 flexbox-equalise">
        <article class="media card card-1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="card-body card-body-left">
                  <h4 class="list-group-item-headline boxFixDw">SAMPLE RESOURCES</h4>
                  <p class="list-group-item-text">Check the quality.</p>
                  <a href="X/" class="button product_type_subscription add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">VIEW NOW</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </article>
      </div>
  
    </div>
</div>
```